Is there a way to salvage the existing water barrier on my shower floor?
Ripped out the tile on the shower floor. Water pen through what looks like an inch of self leveler at the thick spots all on top of the water barrier.gap at the Wall is about an inch and change while the drain in the center is less than a half inch. The floor seemingly was redone, the walls look like they are older. Water barrier is quite low, and not level at all. I really don't want to rip out the walls to redo the water barrier and start from scratch. But if I use the current water barrier it isn't going to drain properly, again it isn't level, there will also be a large gap between wall and floor. Home is a 96' single floor with crawlspace. If any of that matters.
Is there a way to salvage this using the existing water barrier and walls without doing the same thing?
https://ibb.co/SyGT3Nd
https://ibb.co/254HWJ7

For any type of reasonable assessment you will need to post pictures.

@RMDman added a couple if you'd like more just say so. Still bagging up the crap

You did not state why you ripped out the floor so this answer is more to give you an understanding of what you are looking at and why it is there.
What you have is a typically constructed shower with a PVC lined base, ( the gray liner) and a drypack cement floor, what you described as, (... what looks like an inch of self leveler..." )
The PVC liner is there to keep any water that seeps through the floor grout and drypack or mudbase from damaging any subfloor underneath. The liner is attached to the drain flange and allows water to run to the drain through weep channels.  It is not supposed to be level, but have a slight pitch toward the drain. If your liner is not torn and is free of holes it can be reused.
You can rebuild in the same manner with Mud bed mix or a similar product.   This is the step that provides the true slope from the walls to the drain. Here is a video similar to what you need to do
The process to renew will be made difficult, since the flooring tile should be in place before the wall tile. You will need to rebuild the mudbed with a pitch to the drain while allowing a space under the wall tile for the floor tile and the necessary thin set mortar. The alternative is to build a mudbed to the bottom of the walls and then lay floor tile to the walls. (This method is not prefered, but has been done in the past)
In either case, it would be good practice to coat the mudbed with a Waterproofing agent. Use 2 coats. You can tape the edge of the wall tile to protect it while painting on the waterproofing. Let the waterproofing dry 24 hours Then you can tile.
